# Expanding variables in Powershell, to Linux commands

Tags: linux, powershell, putty, plink

On the following Powershell script:

```
$Project_number = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Project Name ie. 02XXX'
$Project_code = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Project Code in capita letters ie. CRE'

plink -load profile1 -batch 'setfacl -Rm d:g:user1:rwX,g:user1:rwX "/FILES/projects/$Project_number $Project_code" && find "/FILES/projects/$Project_number $Project_code" -maxdepth 1 -exec setfacl -m d:g:user1:r-X,g:user1:r-X {} \;'
```

How can I make plink (connected via SSH to a Linux fileserver) expand the variables **$Project_number** and **$Project_code** within the plink command.

At the moment they don't and I receive an error:

```
plink : setfacl: /FILES/projects/ : No such file or directory
```

If I type them manually, it will work, therefore it has to be with my syntax.

Thanks

Comment: If you're running this from powershell, you need to swap the single quotes with double quotes, and then escape the double quotes inside. Single quotes read text as-is, so literally. Say we have a variable of: `$Var = 'text'`. If we wrap the variable in single quotes you get: `'$Var'; $Var`, vs double quotes: `"$Var"; text`. Double quotes allow you to expand a variable, where as single quotes read text literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I was able to figure it out, just needed to use double quotes, remove the quotes on the path of setfacl and escape the space. Like so:

```
plink -load profile1 -batch "setfacl -Rm d:g:user1:rwX,g:user1:rwX /FILES/projects/$Project_number\ $Project_code && find /FILES/projects/$Project_number\ $Project_code -maxdepth 1 -exec setfacl -m d:g:user1:r-X,g:user1:r-X {} \;"
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that the below link has spaces between $Project_number & $Project_code

```
plink -load profile1 -batch 'setfacl -Rm d:g:user1:rwX,g:user1:rwX "/FILES/projects/$Project_number $Project_code" && find "/FILES/projects/$Project_number $Project_code" -maxdepth 1 -exec setfacl -m d:g:user1:r-X,g:user1:r-X {} \;'
```

Have you tried without those spaces ?

Comment: Your answer is not allowing variable expansion